# Linux SED command in Bash script strips ' from string

Tags: linux, sed, strip

I have been putting together a bash script and within it I need to update a file with some neccasary information. The command I am using is below:

```
sudo sed '
/end/ a\
First line to update\
  param 1 'var1'\
  param 2 'var2'\
  param 3 'var3'\
  param 4 'var4'\
end\
' TestFile >TestFileNew
```

Now this should update the file with the data and should look like this:

```
end
First line to update
  param 1 'var1'
  param 2 'var2'
  param 3 'var3'
  param 4 'var4'
end
```

The file does get created and the data is in it however it seems to strip the ' symbols from the text and I don't want this to happen, can anyone please help?? An example of what is actually getting produced is below:

```
end
First line to update
  param 1 var1
  param 2 var2
  param 3 var3
  param 4 var4
end
```

Comment: The single quote before `var1` merely closes the opening single quote that starts your sed script.  See below for the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `""` as the outer quotes:

```
sudo sed "
/end/ a\\
First line to update\\
  param 1 'var1'\\
  param 2 'var2'\\
  param 3 'var3'\\
  param 4 'var4'\\
end\\
" TestFile >TestFileNew
```

Comment: This fixes his sed issue.. Next up, a post regarding the use of sudo and redirection.

Comment: Using `"`'s is this case is acceptable, however I would argue that it is safer to use `'`'s and replace the inner single quotes by `'\''`'s, thus avoiding unexpected interpolation.

Comment: @jordanm Indeed... Examples like this tend to make me a bit twitchy... ;-P

Comment: end
First line to updateparam 1 'var1'
  param 2 'var2' param 3 'var3'
  param 4 'var4'end

Comment: Instead of reading the "\" as a new line it doesn't seem to work, although i do now get the ' in the file lol?

Comment: Can any 1 please help with this last issue?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Igor has already provided an answer that may work for the single quotes.

Regarding the file creation, remember that `sudo` affects the program (`sed`) you're running as its option.  It does not affect redirection, which is handled by your shell.  So if you don't have permission *as a user* to write `TestFileNew`, sudo won't help you, the way you're using it above.

You might be better off creating your output somewhere else, then using sudo to move it into place.

```
sudo sed "/end/ ..." TestFile > /tmp/TestFileNew
sudo mv /tmp/TestFileNew ./TestFileNew
```

Alternately, this whole script could be run with sudo...  I.e. `/path/to/myscript` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed "/end/ ..." TestFile > TestFileNew
```

then:

```
$ sudo /path/to/myscript
```

Then sudo is running **bash** instead of sed, and the privileged bash instance is responsible for handling redirection within the script.

Comment: You can then spare `sudo` inside your script. And most `sed`s provide the `-i` flag.

Comment: @knittl - Not sure what the real purpose here is, or if privileged access is also required to *read* TestFile. if the OP had mentioned he was going to `mv TestFileNew TestFile`, I would have suggested the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to deal with two types of quotes (html and javascript, for example). Then it is very convenient to put sed commands in a script:

```
cat >FILE
end

cat >script.sed
/end/ a\
First line to update\
 param 1 'var1'\
 param 2 'var2'\
 param 3 'var3'\
 param 4 'var4'\
end            

sed -f script.sed FILE 
end
First line to update
  param 1 'var1'
  param 2 'var2'
  param 3 'var3'
  param 4 'var4'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would probably be simpler to use sed's `r` command:

```
$ cat > /tmp/repl << EOF
First line to update
  param 1 'var1'
  param 2 'var2'
  param 3 'var3'
  param 4 'var4'
end
EOF
$ sed '/end/r/tmp/repl' TestFile
$ rm /tmp/repl
```

(I've ignored the sudo/redirect issue, but you probably want to so `sudo sh -c 'sed /end/r/tmp/repl/ TestFile > TestFileNew'`